# Gibt es ein positiveres/stärkeres Wort als "kritikfähig"?

Tags: single-word-request, idiom, synonym

Ich schreibe zur Zeit meinen Lebenslauf und habe dort eine Soft Skills Rubrik. Hier habe ich bislang Dinge wie "Kreativer Erfinder" oder "Hilfsbereiter Teamplayer" reingeschrieben. Nun bin ich jemand der sehr gerne Kritik von anderen hört.

Hierfür scheint mir das Wort "kritikfähig" nicht wirklich passend, da ich nicht nur fähig bin

**Kritik aufzunehmen**, sondern

**Kritik gerne hören möchte**.

Ein Wort wie **kritikwollend** schwirrt mir durch den Kopf, würde aber gerne hören was andere dazu sagen und wie sie diesen Charakterzug in einem Wort beschreiben würden.

Comment: Muss es auf ein Wort beschränkt sein?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naja, wenn du ausdrücken möchtest, dass du *Kritik gerne hören möchtest* – ich interpretiere das mal so, dass du aus der Kritik lernen möchtest – dann wären folgende Wörter passend:

- lernfähig
- lernbereit
- kritikfähig

Im Endeffekt möchtest du ja ausdrücken, dass du aus Kritik *lernen* kannst und der Arbeitgeber sich darauf verlassen kann, dass du Fehler nicht wiederholst bzw. nicht stur aber einsichtig sein kannst und dir das Wohl des Unternehmens über dein Ego geht.

Ich finde aber, *kritikfähig* is so oder so das beste Wort dafür, weil es das eben Beschriebene viel klarer ausdrückt. Die beiden anderen Wörter suggerieren, dass du für dich selber lernen kannst und willst, also auch unabhängig von Kritik als Auslöser. Sie haben also eine etwas andere Bedeutung.

Deinen Vorschlag *kritikwollend* finde ich schräg, weil das auch suggerieren kann, dass du oft Fehler machst und auf Kritik aus bist. Es sollte schon lieber eher neutral sein.

Vielleicht wäre eine Alternative, die sowohl die Lernbereitschaft als auch die Kritikfähigkeit ausdrückt, etwas für dich: *kritik- und lernfähig*

Answer (score 4):

Ich finde @akuzminykh Vorschlag "lernbereit" passend. Weitere Möglichkeiten sind:

- feedbackfähig (Feedback klingt weniger negative als Kritik, da es sowohl positives als auch negatives Feedback geben kann)
- aufgeschlossen für Kritik
- reflektiert

Comment: "Aufgeschlossen für Kritik" trifft den Nagel auf den Kopf und ist unmissverständlich.